# Is this view in django secure?

Tags: python, django, firebase, security, firebase-security

I am building a RESTAPI in Django using the following [library](https://github.com/ronhe/drf-firebase-token-auth) called drf-firebase-token-auth. The client sends a get request with the token_id available in the Authorization header, and the library is expected to handle authentication in Firebase automatically.

But the problem is if I do a simple get request without headers like `curl <url+endpoint>` the library doesn't verify if there's a an Authorization header and try to get a token for verification as if the request happens successfully as if drf-firebase-token-auth didn't raised it to be a problem. So I handled an exception whereas if the get request doesn't have an an authorization header, then raise an exception. But is it secure?

```
from datetime import datetime
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import (
    api_view,
)
from rest_framework.response import Response



# Create your views here.


@api_view(["GET"])
def check_token(request):
    # if token is valid response with current server time
    try:

        if request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]:
            date = datetime.now()
            return Response(
                data="Server time is: " + str(date), status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
    
    except:
        return Response(data="Authorization header unavailable")
```